# Order array of object by another array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

How to order array of object by another array of object.

This is my code:

```
let arrayItem = [
    {
        'id': '#id1',
        'name': 'one',
        'bundle': 'bundle1'
    },
    {
        'id': '#id2',
        'name': 'two',
        'bundle': 'bundle2'
    },
    {
        'id': '#id3',
        'name': 'three',
        'bundle': 'bundle3'
    }
]
```

This is the array for ordering:

```
let orderItem = [
    {
        'id': '#id3',
        'name': 'three'
    },
    {
        'id': '#id1',
        'name': 'one',
    },
    {
        'id': '#id2',
        'name': 'two'
    }
]
```

I need the data like:

```
let resultItem = [
    {
        'id': '#id3',
        'name': 'three',
        'bundle': 'bundle3'
    },
    {
        'id': '#id1',
        'name': 'one',
        'bundle': 'bundle1'
    },
    {
        'id': '#id2',
        'name': 'two',
        'bundle': 'bundle2'
    }
]
```

I want to order array of objects by another array of objects by multiple keys.

Thank you

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have array of objects in your `orderArray`, you first need to find the index of that order object then get the difference of the `index` to get the original array sorted:

```js
let arrayItem = [
    {
        'id': '#id1',
        'name': 'one',
        'bundle': 'bundle1'
    },
    {
        'id': '#id2',
        'name': 'two',
        'bundle': 'bundle2'
    },
    {
        'id': '#id3',
        'name': 'three',
        'bundle': 'bundle3'
    }
];

let orderItem = [
    {
        'id': '#id3',
        'name': 'three'
    },
    {
        'id': '#id1',
        'name': 'one',
    },
    {
        'id': '#id2',
        'name': 'two'
    }
];
arrayItem.sort(function(a, b){
  var aIndex = orderItem.findIndex(({id, name}) => a.id===id && a.name===name);
  var bIndex = orderItem.findIndex(({id, name}) => b.id===id && b.name===name);
  return aIndex - bIndex;
});
console.log(arrayItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Sort** as suggested by @Ankit Agarwal.

Or you can make it work for you using the simple line below. This will do the trick.

```
var orderedItem = orderItem.map(orderObj => 
       arrayItem.find(actualObj => actualObj.id === orderObj.id))
```

> I'm just running `map` on your **orderItem**, `find`ing the
>   corresponding object on your **arrayItem** and then returning the
>   object from your arrayItem.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for storing the index/order and then take the delta of the indices for sorting the array.

```js
var arrayItem = [{ id: '#id1', name: 'one', bundle: 'bundle1' }, { id: '#id2', name: 'two', bundle: 'bundle2' }, { id: '#id3', name: 'three', bundle: 'bundle3' }],
    orderItem = [{ id: '#id3', name: 'three' }, { id: '#id1', name: 'one', }, { id: '#id2', name: 'two' }],
    order = new Map(orderItem.map(({ id }, i) => [id, i]));
    
arrayItem.sort((a, b) => order.get(a.id) - order.get(b.id));

console.log(arrayItem);
```